# Buffer overflow when writing "array"

Tags: list, memory, initialization, overflow

I ran the following code in Visual Studio 2022.

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    int* array=nullptr;
    int length=0;
    int derivedValue=0;

    
    MyClass(int arraySize) :
        length(arraySize),   
        derivedValue(length + 10),  
        array(new int[length ])     

    {
        cout << length << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            array[i] = i;     //C6386  Buffer overflow writing to 'array'o 
    }

        ~MyClass() {
            if (array != nullptr) {
                delete[] array;    // The debugger reports an error on this line
            }
        }
};
```

I tried replacing it with the following code and found that it executes fine and the code does not report errors

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int* array;
    int length;
    int derivedValue;

    MyClass(int arraySize) :
        derivedValue(0),  // 先初始化 derivedValue  
        array(nullptr)    // 再初始化 array  
    {
        length = arraySize;  // 在构造函数体内部初始化 length  
        derivedValue = length + 10;  // 现在可以安全地使用 length 的值来初始化 derivedValue  

        array = new int[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            array[i] = i;
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        if (array != nullptr) {
            delete[] array;
        }
    }
};
```

I tried to use vscode   cmake   msys2 to execute the previous error code and found that it could also be executed normally.

Comment: I asked my Chinese friend, and it seemed to work out, just needed to put  public:
    int length = 0;
    int* array=nullptr;
   
    int derivedValue=0;

Answer (score 0):

from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

> Then, non-static data member are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition

this means that despite it "seems" to initialize variables in that order (as declared in constructor):

1. length(arraySize),
2. derivedValue(length + 10),
3. array(new int[length ])

it is not true, real order is:

1. array(new int[length ])
2. length(arraySize),
3. derivedValue(length + 10),

and here is the problem, during initialization of `array` variable `length` is 0, this is why you're getting errors

you can either change declaration order, ie move `array` below `length` or you can use `arraySize` in constructor, so order will not matter